# Unable to execute Preparedstatement batch JDBC statements

Tags: jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

This is the code below where I am trying to execute the batch PreparedStatement. These statements are running fine without batch but I am unable to batch 
insert using the "?" parameters .

Getting the following error :

`java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1`

Same I am unable to insert using Statement batch insert too.

```java
  public void insertValuesInTotalResponseWithPSwithBatch(List<A> details) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn;
        int batch_count = 0;

        conn = MySqlConnectionUtility.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        for (A record : details) {
            if (!record.getLon().trim().equals("bac")) {
                System.out.println("the record is " + record);


                String query = "INSERT INTO AwithbatchwitPS " + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(record.getOne()));
                ps.setFloat(2, Float.parseFloat(record.getTwo()));
                ps.setFloat(3, Float.parseFloat(record.getThree()));
                ps.setString(4, record.getDayofyear());
                ps.setDouble(5, Double.parseDouble(record.getFive()));
                ps.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(record.getCount()));

                System.out.println(ps);

                ps.addBatch(query);
                System.out.println("Btach1 coutn1 is " + batch_count);
                batch_count++;
                System.out.println("Btach2 coutn2 is " + batch_count);
                if (batch_count % 200 == 0) {
                    try {

                        ps.executeBatch();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Btach coutn is " + batch_count);
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        conn.commit();
                        ps.clearBatch();
                    }
                    batch_count = 0;
                }
            }
            details_size = details.size();

        }
        if (batch_count != 0) {
            try {
                ps.executeBatch();
                conn.commit();
            } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
            batch_count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `prepareStatement()` should only be called **once** outside the `for (A record ...)` loop

Comment: Move preparing the statement outside the loop, your current code will only execute once very 200 records and discard all other records when the statement handle is replaced with a new one when you prepare.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization suggestion .. but again my program throws this error.

`java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1`  Even though the query is fine